# Python Pandas - Process folder of CSV files and output final combined CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying read in a folder of CSV files, process them one by one to remove duplicates, and then add them to a master dataframe which will then finally be output to a CSV. I have this...

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys

output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2'])

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("sourcefolder", topdown=False):

    for name in files:

        data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, name), usecols=[1], skiprows=1)
        output.append(data)

output.to_csv("output.csv", index=False, encoding='utf8')
```

But my output CSV is empty apart fom the column names. Anyone any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: if your folder is correct try:
`output = output.append(data)`

Comment: @DeepSpace if you were talking about a list you're correct but output is a dataframe and so the result is the two frames added together

Comment: don't append to dataframes, use concat. merge or update, think of it like a database. if you instead set `output = []` then append to it, then call `pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(output))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas dataframes don't act like a list so you can't use append like that try:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys

output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2'])

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("sourcefolder", topdown=False):

    for name in files:

        data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, name), usecols=[1], skiprows=1)
        output = output.append(data)

output_df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False, encoding='utf8')
```

Alternatively you can make output a list of dataframes and then use pd.concat to create a consolidated dataframe at the end, depending on the volume of data this could be more efficient

Answer (score 1):

The built in pandas method concat is also pretty good. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys

output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2'])

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("sourcefolder", topdown=False):

    for name in files:

        data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, name), usecols=[1], skiprows=1)
        output = pd.concat([output, data], columns=output.columns)

output_df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False, encoding='utf8')
```